# flutter doctor does not work due to downloading error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-doctor

I am trying to use flutter, but when I use the command “flutter doctor -v”, it shows the following error.

```
TECHNOLOG3:~ kazuhiropro$ which flutter
/Users/kazuhiropro/development/flutter/bin/flutter
TECHNOLOG3:~ kazuhiropro$ flutter doctor -v
Downloading Darwin x64 Dart SDK from Flutter engine e1302d7bb187aed2430f026de7ca59f0b21e8028...
dyld[3493]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssh2.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
Reason: tried: '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file)
/Users/kazuhiropro/development/flutter/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.sh: line 186: 3493 Abort trap: 6 curl ${verbose_curl} --retry 3 --continue-at - --location --output "$DART_SDK_ZIP" "$DART_SDK_URL" 2>&1
/Users/kazuhiropro/development/flutter/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.sh: line 156: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
dyld[3494]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libssh2.1.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
Reason: tried: '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/kazuhiropro/opt/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libssh2.1.dylib' (no such file)
/Users/kazuhiropro/development/flutter/bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.sh: line 186: 3494 Abort trap: 6 curl ${verbose_curl} --retry 3 --location --output "$DART_SDK_ZIP" "$DART_SDK_URL" 2>&1

Failed to retrieve the Dart SDK from: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/e1302d7bb187aed2430f026de7ca59f0b21e8028/dart-sdk-darwin-x64.zip
If you're located in China, please see this page:
https://flutter.dev/community/china
```

I am not living in China.
How can I solve this?
It is helpful if you tell me the solution…

If you need additional information regarding this, please let me know.
thanks.

I replaced the file, engine.version, but still error exists as shown in the image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW0Qu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

kindly do check in flutter/bin/internal called engine.version is where the "head" issue lies. I went to the flutter GitHub repo and found the same file then just replaced all the content of the file with what was in their repo.

Here's the [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/bin/internal/engine.version)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I replaced the engine.version, but still error occurs… (i added new error in the original post)